# Incoming emails are not visible Postfix

Tags: postfix, dovecot, thunderbird

After 3 days I've decided to seek some help with postfix. I can send emails but I don't see the inbound emails! First it was working into Queue, when I tried to fix it to deliver to the right inbox it got worst. No bounce emails from gmail or protonmail.The emails are nowhere to be found.
No logs from mail.log/ I suspect its spamAssassin but I disabled it for the moment. Please help

#**main.cf** #

```
#smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#smtpd_use_tls=yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
#smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = example.com
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 189.180.0.0/16
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_protocols = all
#mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
#Virtual domains, users, and aliases
#virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
#sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
allow_percent_hack = no
mynetworks_style = subnet
relayhost = 
#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#mtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
#smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot

smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
# Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP
#virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
inet_interfaces = all


append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
message_size_limit = 4194304
readme_directory = no
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (CentOS)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_transport = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth


virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mariadb-vusers.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
```

#**Master.cf** #

```
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o content_filter=spamassassin
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file=${config_directory}/dh2048.pem
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 # -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 # -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================

# ====================================================================
#

maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#

#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix    -    n    n    -    2    pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}



dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to re-enable smtp, which for some reason you have disabled in `master.cf`. Then you will receive email again, and can begin working on delivering it to mailboxes.

```
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

Comment: Thanks, just updated and sent 3 emails, no luck. With "postmap /etc/postfix/master.cf" and restarted postfix

Comment: Now you can check your logs.

Comment: nothing, i've checked  mail.log, mail.err, syslog, dovecot.log.

Comment: Better check your MX records, then.

Comment: Apparently something really screwed up. I can't telnet to localhost. "sudo ufw disable" didn't help either.

Comment: I had to reinstall postfix, now I'm receiving mails.